# asp.net formatting an email

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, .net-3.5

I am working on an application that involves the user clicking on a hyperlink to popup an outlook email template. I have the SendTo values, and the subject values.
How do I enter text into the body of the email?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the hyperlink you can add the `?body=` variable after the email address. Formatting the body will be a challenge because for symbols like spaces you have to use hex codes (space = `%20`, newline = `%0D`). I don't know what your design criteria are, but most of the time I prefer to create a form with the desired input fields and let .NET handle the sending of the e-mail message on the submit.

Answer (score 1):

Are you searching for this?

```
<a href="mailto:person@test.com?subject=x&body=y">...</a>
```

Comment: how would I add a line break within the body text?